# Not getting full xml response using nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri, open-uri

I'm trying to get response from picasa api to get albums/photos. Strange thing happens, when I do it. I'm getting not full response from my code and get a full response from google addon "postman".
Here's my code:

```
def self.getUserAlbums  
    url = "https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/" + @user.uid
    puts @user.uid
    puts url
    doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(url))

    puts doc
end
```

And here's the response that I get:

```
https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/107097732897061020403
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/" xmlns:gphoto="http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
  <id>https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/107097732897061020403</id>
  <updated>2014-09-04T12:22:34.062Z</updated>
  <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007#user"/>
  <title type="text">107097732897061020403</title>
  <subtitle type="text"/>
  <icon>https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-ciT1cTht4tU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/2KCtta9zU8Y/s64-c/107097732897061020403.jpg</icon>
  <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/107097732897061020403"/>
  <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="https://picasaweb.google.com/107097732897061020403"/>
  <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007#slideshow" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" href="https://photos.gstatic.com/media/slideshow.swf?host=picasaweb.google.com&amp;RGB=0x000000&amp;feed=https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/107097732897061020403?alt%3Drss"/>
  <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/107097732897061020403?start-index=1&amp;max-results=1000"/>
  <author>
    <name>Strange man</name>
    <uri>https://picasaweb.google.com/107097732897061020403</uri>
  </author>
  <generator version="1.00" uri="http://picasaweb.google.com/">Picasaweb</generator>
  <openSearch:totalResults>1</openSearch:totalResults>
  <openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
  <openSearch:itemsPerPage>1000</openSearch:itemsPerPage>
  <gphoto:user>107097732897061020403</gphoto:user>
  <gphoto:nickname>Strange man</gphoto:nickname>
  <gphoto:thumbnail>https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-ciT1cTht4tU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/2KCtta9zU8Y/s64-c/107097732897061020403.jpg</gphoto:thumbnail>
  <entry>
    <id>https://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/107097732897061020403/albumid/5995150641832070833</id>
    <published>2014-03-26T17:26:22.000Z</published>
    <updated>2014-03-26T17:26:22.019Z</updated>
    <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007#album"/>
    <title type="text">Profile Photos</title>
    <summary type="text">Album for profile photos</summary>
    <rights type="text">public</rights>
    <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/107097732897061020403/albumid/5995150641832070833"/>
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="https://picasaweb.google.com/107097732897061020403/ProfilePhotos"/>
    <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/107097732897061020403/albumid/5995150641832070833"/>
    <author>
      <name>Strange man</name>
      <uri>https://picasaweb.google.com/107097732897061020403</uri>
    </author>
    <gphoto:id>5995150641832070833</gphoto:id>
    <gphoto:name>ProfilePhotos</gphoto:name>
    <gphoto:location/>
    <gphoto:access>public</gphoto:access>
    <gphoto:timestamp>1395854782000</gphoto:timestamp>
    <gphoto:numphotos>0</gphoto:numphotos>
    <gphoto:user>107097732897061020403</gphoto:user>
    <gphoto:nickname>Strange man</gphoto:nickname>
    <gphoto:albumType>ProfilePhotos</gphoto:albumType>
    <media:group>
      <media:content url="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-3SHSUfpLzb8/UzMNvr1bDrE/AAAAAAAAAAc/eEGmx-4YiEg/ProfilePhotos.jpg" type="image/jpeg" medium="image"/>
      <media:credit>Strange man</media:credit>
      <media:description type="plain"/>
      <media:keywords/>
      <media:thumbnail url="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-3SHSUfpLzb8/UzMNvr1bDrE/AAAAAAAAAAc/eEGmx-4YiEg/s160-c/ProfilePhotos.jpg" height="160" width="160"/>
      <media:title type="plain">Profile Photos</media:title>
    </media:group>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

But when I use google addon postman:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<feed 
    xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' 
    xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/' 
    xmlns:gphoto='http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007' 
    xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'>
    <id>https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/107097732897061020403</id>
    <updated>2014-09-04T12:22:34.062Z</updated>
    <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007#user'/>
    <title type='text'>107097732897061020403</title>
    <subtitle type='text'/>
    <icon>https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-ciT1cTht4tU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/2KCtta9zU8Y/s64-c/107097732897061020403.jpg</icon>
    <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/107097732897061020403'/>
    <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#post' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/107097732897061020403?tok=QUI1UGxRWmktbk5VOU1lSm01VjB2a1hoNGR1UzhORFhSQToxNDA5ODM0MjE0MzA3'/>
    <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='https://picasaweb.google.com/107097732897061020403'/>
    <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007#slideshow' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' href='https://photos.gstatic.com/media/slideshow.swf?host=picasaweb.google.com&amp;RGB=0x000000&amp;feed=https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/107097732897061020403?alt%3Drss'/>
    <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/107097732897061020403?start-index=1&amp;max-results=1000'/>
    <author>
        <name>Strange man</name>
        <uri>https://picasaweb.google.com/107097732897061020403</uri>
    </author>
    <generator version='1.00' uri='http://picasaweb.google.com/'>Picasaweb</generator>
    <openSearch:totalResults>3</openSearch:totalResults>
    <openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
    <openSearch:itemsPerPage>1000</openSearch:itemsPerPage>
    <gphoto:user>107097732897061020403</gphoto:user>
    <gphoto:nickname>Strange man</gphoto:nickname>
    <gphoto:thumbnail>https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-ciT1cTht4tU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/2KCtta9zU8Y/s64-c/107097732897061020403.jpg</gphoto:thumbnail>
    <gphoto:quotalimit>16106127360</gphoto:quotalimit>
    <gphoto:quotacurrent>0</gphoto:quotacurrent>
    <gphoto:maxPhotosPerAlbum>2000</gphoto:maxPhotosPerAlbum>
    <entry>
        <id>https://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/107097732897061020403/albumid/6055182888376766577</id>
        <published>2014-09-04T12:02:09.000Z</published>
        <updated>2014-09-04T12:22:34.062Z</updated>
        <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007#album'/>
        <title type='text'>September 4, 2014</title>
        <summary type='text'/>
        <rights type='text'>protected</rights>
        <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/107097732897061020403/albumid/6055182888376766577'/>
        <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='https://picasaweb.google.com/107097732897061020403/September42014'/>
        <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/107097732897061020403/albumid/6055182888376766577'/>
        <link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/107097732897061020403/albumid/6055182888376766577/9?tok=QUI1UGxRWW9NRjVubkVZQjdIZEotOVY2VFlhM051YllHZzoxNDA5ODM0MjE0MzA3'/>
        <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007#accessControlList' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/107097732897061020403/albumid/6055182888376766577/acl'/>
        <author>
            <name>Strange man</name>
            <uri>https://picasaweb.google.com/107097732897061020403</uri>
        </author>
        <gphoto:id>6055182888376766577</gphoto:id>
        <gphoto:name>September42014</gphoto:name>
        <gphoto:location/>
        <gphoto:access>protected</gphoto:access>
        <gphoto:timestamp>1409832129000</gphoto:timestamp>
        <gphoto:numphotos>6</gphoto:numphotos>
        <gphoto:numphotosremaining>1994</gphoto:numphotosremaining>
        <gphoto:bytesUsed>832905</gphoto:bytesUsed>
        <gphoto:user>107097732897061020403</gphoto:user>
        <gphoto:nickname>Strange man</gphoto:nickname>
        <media:group>
            <media:content url='https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-pX41vnK92K4/VAhUwVe4kHE/AAAAAAAAACA/WSmDsRTuWqo/September42014.jpg' type='image/jpeg' medium='image'/>
            <media:credit>Strange man</media:credit>
            <media:description type='plain'/>
            <media:keywords/>
            <media:thumbnail url='https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-pX41vnK92K4/VAhUwVe4kHE/AAAAAAAAACA/WSmDsRTuWqo/s160-c/September42014.jpg' height='160' width='160'/>
            <media:title type='plain'>September 4, 2014</media:title>
        </media:group>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <id>https://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/107097732897061020403/albumid/6054471120618425345</id>
        <published>2014-09-02T14:00:07.000Z</published>
        <updated>2014-09-02T14:29:53.542Z</updated>
        <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007#album'/>
        <title type='text'>2014-09-02</title>
        <summary type='text'/>
        <rights type='text'>protected</rights>
        <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/107097732897061020403/albumid/6054471120618425345'/>
        <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='https://picasaweb.google.com/107097732897061020403/20140902'/>
        <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/107097732897061020403/albumid/6054471120618425345'/>
        <link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/107097732897061020403/albumid/6054471120618425345/7?tok=QUI1UGxRWWZncVExZ3p4aGhuOGN5TDdZaGVmT00zT0puZzoxNDA5ODM0MjE0MzA3'/>
        <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007#accessControlList' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/107097732897061020403/albumid/6054471120618425345/acl'/>
        <author>
            <name>Strange man</name>
            <uri>https://picasaweb.google.com/107097732897061020403</uri>
        </author>
        <gphoto:id>6054471120618425345</gphoto:id>
        <gphoto:name>20140902</gphoto:name>
        <gphoto:location/>
        <gphoto:access>protected</gphoto:access>
        <gphoto:timestamp>1409666407000</gphoto:timestamp>
        <gphoto:numphotos>3</gphoto:numphotos>
        <gphoto:numphotosremaining>1997</gphoto:numphotosremaining>
        <gphoto:bytesUsed>421306</gphoto:bytesUsed>
        <gphoto:user>107097732897061020403</gphoto:user>
        <gphoto:nickname>Strange man</gphoto:nickname>
        <media:group>
            <media:content url='https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-zxKJrQaBe3E/VAXNZ_9SjAE/AAAAAAAAABE/DztgeKHgQVM/20140902.jpg' type='image/jpeg' medium='image'/>
            <media:credit>Strange man</media:credit>
            <media:description type='plain'/>
            <media:keywords/>
            <media:thumbnail url='https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-zxKJrQaBe3E/VAXNZ_9SjAE/AAAAAAAAABE/DztgeKHgQVM/s160-c/20140902.jpg' height='160' width='160'/>
            <media:title type='plain'>2014-09-02</media:title>
        </media:group>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <id>https://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/107097732897061020403/albumid/5995150641832070833</id>
        <published>2014-03-26T17:26:22.000Z</published>
        <updated>2014-03-26T17:26:22.019Z</updated>
        <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007#album'/>
        <title type='text'>Profile Photos</title>
        <summary type='text'>Album for profile photos</summary>
        <rights type='text'>public</rights>
        <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/107097732897061020403/albumid/5995150641832070833'/>
        <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='https://picasaweb.google.com/107097732897061020403/ProfilePhotos'/>
        <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/107097732897061020403/albumid/5995150641832070833'/>
        <link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/107097732897061020403/albumid/5995150641832070833/1?tok=QUI1UGxRWklzV0VmX1JTQTlUalQ2dGdCY1NvQXdOdHB5QToxNDA5ODM0MjE0MzA3'/>
        <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007#accessControlList' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/107097732897061020403/albumid/5995150641832070833/acl'/>
        <author>
            <name>Strange man</name>
            <uri>https://picasaweb.google.com/107097732897061020403</uri>
        </author>
        <gphoto:id>5995150641832070833</gphoto:id>
        <gphoto:name>ProfilePhotos</gphoto:name>
        <gphoto:location/>
        <gphoto:access>public</gphoto:access>
        <gphoto:timestamp>1395854782000</gphoto:timestamp>
        <gphoto:numphotos>0</gphoto:numphotos>
        <gphoto:numphotosremaining>2000</gphoto:numphotosremaining>
        <gphoto:bytesUsed>0</gphoto:bytesUsed>
        <gphoto:user>107097732897061020403</gphoto:user>
        <gphoto:nickname>Strange man</gphoto:nickname>
        <gphoto:albumType>ProfilePhotos</gphoto:albumType>
        <media:group>
            <media:content url='https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-3SHSUfpLzb8/UzMNvr1bDrE/AAAAAAAAAAc/eEGmx-4YiEg/ProfilePhotos.jpg' type='image/jpeg' medium='image'/>
            <media:credit>Strange man</media:credit>
            <media:description type='plain'/>
            <media:keywords/>
            <media:thumbnail url='https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-3SHSUfpLzb8/UzMNvr1bDrE/AAAAAAAAAAc/eEGmx-4YiEg/s160-c/ProfilePhotos.jpg' height='160' width='160'/>
            <media:title type='plain'>Profile Photos</media:title>
        </media:group>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

So if your lazy as me to read the whole xml, here's the difference, postman after request returns 3 albums in tag , but my code returns only 1 album(last).If you want to check yourself, the request is first line of first response. Thx for answering.

Comment: It's not a Nokogiri problem. Using a browser or with a `curl` method, I always get 1 entry. With Postman too. How do you get your 3 entries ? In my opinion, that's just you need an authentication. Your Rails code have not, your browser have it.

Comment: Look at the second response or do yourself a request "https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/107097732897061020403" and see that there're 3 entry tags not 1.And I already have authetication, without that I wouldn't have got uid.

Comment: No. I have 1 entry. By authentication I said "google account authorization". You should be logged in G+, Gmail, Picasa or something else, and so you can see 3 albums. Me, I'm logged with my account, and I have no rights to see the 2 other entries! They certainly are not public, instead of the last one. See the response : 2 are `protected`, one is `public` (`<rights type='text'>protected</rights>`)

Comment: I meant "google account authorization" too, I did authorization with google. As for 3 entries, if you say, that I can see 3 different entries, because I had logged in with 3 different authorizations, why do 3 entries are different? If you look at tag numphotos, entry represent each album.

Comment: But you're right, I have logged out from google and tried to do a request and had a same response as in my program. But I don't really understand, why, when I authorize , it doesn't see my authorization.